# CORS Error while calling .Net WebAPI from Axios

Tags: c#, reactjs, asp.net-core, .net-core, cors

I have a login form from where I am calling the .Net API from react using `Axios`

```
axios
.post(
    'https://localhost:5001/login',
    {
        email: 'abc@gmail.com',
        password: '12345',
    },
    {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        },
    },
)
.then(function (response) {
    console.log(response)
})
.catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error)
})
```

Below is the code from Startup.cs to handle CORS on API side

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllers();
    services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
    {
        c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "API", Version = "v1" });
    });
    services.AddCors(option => 
    {
        option.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy", policy =>
        {
            policy.AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader().WithOrigins("http://localhost:3000/");
        });
    }); 
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        app.UseSwagger();
        app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "API v1"));
    }
    // app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseRouting();
    app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");
    app.UseAuthorization();
    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllers();
    });
}
```

In browser's console I am getting these errors:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://localhost:5001/login' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Error: Network Error
    at createError (createError.js:16)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (xhr.js:84)

POST https://localhost:5001/login net::ERR_FAILED
```

I have tested the API using `REST Client` extension of VS code. The API works properly but getting these errors when called from browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to move AddCors to the top of config section, before AddControllers. Also change the syntax and remove  trailing "/" from an url:

```
services.AddCors(o => o.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy", builder =>
            {
                builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:3000")
                       .AllowAnyMethod()
                       .AllowAnyHeader();
            }));
```

Comment: Hi @Sergey, removing the trailing "/" in my existing code worked. But why that "/" was causing the issue?

Comment: If the URL terminates with /, the comparison of ulrs always returns false.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue. We started using the "withCredentials" options on axios to include the necessary cookies.

```
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
```

That broke the existing API calls even though we had used the AddCors option.

Turns out we were missing the [AllowCredentials()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-6.0#credentials-in-cross-origin-requests) option. This option allows cross-origin credentials to be sent to the server.

```
        services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("AllowSpecificOrigins",
                 builder =>
                 {
                    builder
                        .SetIsOriginAllowedToAllowWildcardSubdomains()
                        .WithOrigins(                           
                            "https://*.mycorpdomain.com", 
                            )
                        .AllowAnyMethod()
                        .AllowAnyHeader()
                        .AllowCredentials();
                 });
        });
```